# How does my boolean HashSet from a span have 3 values?

Tags: c#

I vaguely understand this, but I would like a concrete explanation as to what's happening. If I construct a `HashSet<bool>` with data originally from a `byte` array, why exactly does it keep duplicate values? I've tried to debug this but once I have a `bool` array, all the elements appear like standard `bool`s.

.Net Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/QOll01

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2 };
ReadOnlySpan<byte> span = new(bytes);
ReadOnlySpan<bool> boolSpan = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, bool>(span);
bool[] bools = boolSpan.ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", bools)); // False, True, True

Console.WriteLine(new HashSet<bool>(bools).Count); // 3??
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", new HashSet<bool>(bools))); // False, True, True
```

Comment: Probably like this --> `HashSet<bool> set = new HashSet<bool>(boolSpan.ToArray());`

Comment: Actually, `bools[1]==bools[2]` gives `false`, so the the elements are not the same from point of view of standard comparer. And after this the behavior of `HashSet` becomes obvious. But I did not find out why the comparator behaves in such a way.

Comment: I was thrown off by Visual Studio's debugger, where in the immediate window `bools[1]==bools[2]` is `true` (!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bool`s are represented by 8 bits, but only `0` and `1` are emitted/expected by C#'s compiler. You've introduced `2` as a boolean. Since C# is expecting either 0 or 1, the `Equals(object)` method on the boolean returns an incorrect value.

```cs
EqualityComparer<bool>.Default.Equals((unsafebool)1, (unsafebool)2); // False; visually: true != true
```

So you get 3 values in your `HashSet`.

> ### Representation of Boolean Values
>
> The C# and VB compilers represent `true` (`True`) and `false` (`False`) `bool` (`Boolean`) values with the single byte values `1` and `0`, respectively, and assume that any boolean values that they are working with are restricted to being represented by these two underlying values. The ECMA 335 CLI specification permits a "true" boolean value to be represented by any nonzero value. If you use boolean values that have an underlying representation other than `0` or `1`, you can get unexpected results. This can occur in `unsafe` code in C#, or by interoperating with a language that permits other values. To avoid these unexpected results, it is the programmer's responsibility to normalize such incoming values.
>
> See also https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/24652

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/compilers/Boolean%20Representation.md

> A CLI Boolean type occupies 1 byte in memory. A bit pattern of all zeroes denotes a value of
> false. A bit pattern with any one or more bits set (analogous to a non-zero integer) denotes a
> value of true. For the purpose of stack operations boolean values are treated as unsigned 1-byte integers

[ECMA 335 specification (§III.1.1.2) p. 293](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_6th_edition_june_2012.pdf#page=319)

Comment: Ah, seeing `unsafebool`, I came up with this `unsafe { int ia = 1; bool a = *(bool*)&ia; int ib = 2; bool b = *(bool*)&ib; }` and `a != b`. That helps. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

My guess would be that the memory for a `bool` can actually be populated with any data. If you set it explicitly then it is probably populated with all 0s or all 1s but it can actually be populated with anything and any value that is not zero is interpreted as `true`. Because you are creating your values from numbers, the two `true` values actually do contain different numbers in memory so, while they are the same when interpreted as `bool` values, they are actually being compared as numbers under the hood and are thus not equal.

To test, I changed this:

```cs
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2 };
```

to this:

```cs
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 1, 2 };
```

and the output was this:

```
False, True, True, True, True
3
False, True, True
```

That appears to support the theory.